# how to mount a file on another file

Tags: mount

I am trying to mount `/boot/config-4.14.90-v8` on to `/usr/src/linux/.config`. I've tried:

```
rpi-4.14.y:linux Necktwi$ sudo mount -o loop,ro -t vfat /boot/config-4.14.90-v8-g6d68e517b3ec /usr/src/linux/.config
mount: /usr/src/linux/.config: cannot mount /dev/loop0 read-only.
```

notice the error `cannot mount /dev/loop0 read-only`.

`rootfs` is `btrfs`
`/boot` is `vfat`
`/usr/src` is `nfs` (I mounted remote server's `/usr/src`)

---

I tried `mount --bind` but it failed.

```
rpi-4.14.y:linux Necktwi$ sudo mount --bind /boot/config-4.14.90-v8-g6d68e517b3ec /usr/src/linux/.config
mount: /usr/src/linux/.config: bind /boot/config-4.14.90-v8-g6d68e517b3ec failed.
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? `/boot/config-4.14.90-v8-g6d68e517b3ec` is normally a ASCII file which does not hold a filesystem and cannot be mounted therefore.

Comment: I'm trying to maintain single `/usr/src` across network for different machines of different architectures. their kernel config differ but have same source files. so i want to mount respective kernel config on to `/usr/src/linux/.config`. some one at *#linux* suggested me to use loop to mount files.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to mount a single file, so that the contents of that file are seen on the mount point, then what you want is a *bind mount*.

You can accomplish that with the following command:

```
# mount --bind /boot/config-4.14.90-v8 /usr/src/linux/.config
```

You can use `-o ro` to make it read-only on the `/usr/src/linux/.config` path.

For more details, look for bind mounts in the man page for [mount(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).

---

Loop devices do something similar, yet different. They mount a *filesystem* stored into a regular file onto another directory.

So if you had a vfat or ext4 etc. filesystem stored into a file, say `/vol/myfs.img`, you could then mount it into a *directory*, say `/mnt/myfs`, using the following command:

```
# mount -o loop /vol/myfs.img /mnt/myfs
```

You can pass it `-t vfat` etc. to force the filesystem type.

Note that the `-o loop` is usually not needed, since `mount` will figure that out by you trying to mount a file and will do that for you automatically.

Also, mounting a file with `-o loop` (or automatically detected) is a shortcut to mapping that file to a `/dev/loopX` device, which you can also do using `losetup`, and then running the mount command, such as `mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/myfs`. See the man page for [losetup(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/losetup) for details on loop devices.

Comment: Nice one, didn't consider that one can `bind-mount` files.

Comment: I always use --bind to mount one directory on to another. Damn, I should have just tried with files!

Comment: `mount --bind` failed. edited the question with its output.

Comment: @neckTwi Bind mount should have worked. As soon as both source and target are regular files (or both are directories, but not mixed one regular file and one directory), it should work. If that's really the case, can you check whether there is something else on your system (like SELinux or AppArmor perhaps) which might be blocking the mount? Check dmesg, audit and system logs... Otherwise, try running the command under strace to see if you find the actual errno of the mount failure, that might be helpful too.

Comment: don't know why it didn't work before!

Comment: @Necktwi, then delete the part of your question where you state it failed.

Answer (score 3):

While you cannot mount a normal file, you could create a symbolic link */usr/src/linux/.config* pointing to the specific local kernel config file. As your configs differ, this method has its own traps as you also would have to maintain a symbolic link locally like */boot/config-default* pointing to the actual config file which then can be used in the NFS share.

Better would be to use the environment variable `KCONFIG_CONFIG` to point to alternate kernel configuration file.

```
make menuconfig KCONFIG_CONFIG=/boot/config-4.14.90-v8
```

From [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig.txt):

```
KCONFIG_CONFIG
--------------------------------------------------
This environment variable can be used to specify a default kernel config
file name to override the default name of ".config".
```

Comment: implemented your solution. I hope those software that check for kernel config, check the `KCONFIG_CONFIG`.

Comment: The Linux kernel can bind mount specific files. I double-checked right now. Maybe the answer could be updated with additional context, to explain why it says the contrary. E.g. prepare /tmp/1.txt as a file, and run `mount --bind /tmp/1.txt /tmp/2.txt`