# How is it possible to have linux config files and normal files as mountpoints

Tags: filesystems, mount

In my current project, seeing mount command output showing files as mountpoints mounted on tmpfs.

```
tmpfs on /etc/hostname type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=52724k)
tmpfs on /etc/hosts type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=52724k)
tmpfs on /etc/passwd type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=52724k)
tmpfs on /etc/ntp.conf type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=52724k)
tmpfs on /etc/resolv.conf type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=52724k)
```

By **manpage** description, mount takes only directory as mountpoints.

I tried to mount the file as done in above way but its not working for me.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home# file /tmp/agner
/tmp/agner: ASCII text

root@raspberrypi:/home# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp/agner
mount: mount point /tmp/agner is not a directory
```

**Bind mounts syntax:**

```
 mount --bind olddir newdir
 mount --rbind olddir newdir
```

'/tmp' directory is already mounted into tmpfs.

```
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw)
```

I attempted below combinations but getting 'fs' not exist error.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home# mount --rbind tmpfs /tmp/agner
mount: special device tmpfs does not exist
root@raspberrypi:/home# mount --bind tmpfs /tmp/agner
mount: special device tmpfs does not exist
root@raspberrypi:/home# mount --bind /tmp/ /tmp/agner
mount: mount point /tmp/agner is not a directory
```

When specifying '-t tmpfs' filesystem option in addition, then mount manpage is showing up.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home# mount -t tmpfs --bind tmpfs /tmp/agner
```

So what option in mount command is required to achieve this.

Comment: It can be done with a bind mount. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495421/how-to-mount-a-file-on-another-file.

Comment: Not really, Sorry I was not able to mount the file with bind mount. I am getting errors only.

Comment: did you intend `mount --bind /source/FILE /target/FILE` ?

Comment: @Archemar : mountinfo file and the bind option helped. Thanks!!!

Comment: @berndbausch - Thanks for your suggestion and it worked finally after few experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **bind mount** is working.

I just didnt understand at the first.
But after looking into **`/proc/self/mountinfo`**, i got the better understanding.

[https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](http://Kernel%20Doc)

**shared:X** Optional field is the catch and **Mount ID**, **Parent ID** also gave the clue.

Existing case:

```
47 14 0:30 /hostname /etc/hostname rw,relatime shared:21 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=52724k
52 14 0:30 /etc/passwd /etc/passwd rw,relatime shared:21 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=52724k

37 34 0:30 / /DATA/var/volatile rw,relatime shared:21 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=52724k
36 35 0:30 / /var/volatile rw,relatime shared:21 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=52724k
```

Created/copied the file in /var/volatile:

```
touch /var/volatile/hostname
mount --bind /var/volatile/hostname /etc/hostname
```