# How to configure fstab to mount a specific file only?

Tags: fstab

How should I configure fstab to mount a specific file only? The file is in a directory which contains other directories and files, besides the file I intend to mount.

Comment: What operating system are you using? On Linux you should be able to set up a bind mount -- assuming the directory tree the file sits in is already mounted somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't mount files, you mount filesystems on directories. So, what you want isn't possible.

You can mount the whole filesystem containing the file somewhere else, and use e.g. a symbolic link (as created using `ln -s`) to "alias" it into the place you want to have it.

(this still sounds like a bit of a "strange" problem; maybe really ask about the problem you're solving by trying to mount a single file, or a directory without subdirectories!)

Comment: Not really. As @fra-san suggests in its comment you can actually mount one single file via a *bind mount*. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495421/how-to-mount-a-file-on-another-file

Comment: Yes, indeed, but the use cases where you want that instead of symlinks are rather sporadic; it would really be important to know what is being solved here

Comment: `mount --bind olddir newdir` -> the bind approach doesn't work on files

Comment: hence, symlinks!